# How to dynamically create arguments as functions from an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects(can be of any length):

```
[
    {
        "operator": "sortBy",
        "value": "price"
    },
    {
        "operator": "startAt",
        "value": "7"
    },
    ...

]
```

where `operator` is a name of a function that can be imported from the JS module:

```
{
  sortBy: f(),
  startAt: f(),
  ...
}
```

and `value` is any value with a type  of `string` or `number`.

##### How can I create functions from this array and pass them as arguments to another function?

For example:

```
import * as Utils from "@externalPackage";

const filters = [
    {
        "operator": "sortBy",
        "value": "price"
    },
    {
        "operator": "startAt",
        "value": "7"
    }
]

const anotherFunction = (arg1, arg2, ...) => ...
//this function can have any number of arguments

const helperFunction = (arr)=>//What should I do here with filters array to get a list of callable arguments(=>Utils.sortBy("price"), Utils.startAt(7)) ?//

const result = anotherFunction(helperFunction(filters)) 
                               ^ ^ ^
                               | | |
//This should be transformed in anotherFunction(Utils.sortBy("price"), Utils.startAt(7))//
```

Comment: You typed it out in pseudo code... `Utils.sortBy("price")`, you can simply translate that to a map call. `const helperFunction = (arr)=> arr.map(({operator, value})=> (x) => Utils[operator](value))`. But it's unclear how the Util functions are being called or what is being passed to them. Voting to close for clarity.

Comment: `sortBy: f()` should be `sortBy: f`. You don't want to call the function when creating the object, you just want to store a reference to the function in the object.

Comment: Assuming I'm reading correctly, you could build out the functions you need into strings then use something like this to parse them: https://gist.github.com/lamberta/3768814

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the Util functions to be called immediately (e.g. they generate something, and *that* will be passed to the other function), **you can use `Array.map` to map the filters into the results of calling the specified Util functions**:

```js
const mapFilters = (filters) => {
  return filters.map(({ operator, value }) => Utils[operator](value));
};
```

And then call the other function, spreading the resulting array as the parameters:

```js
const result = anotherFunction(...mapFilters(filters));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.map()` to map the functions then you can spread it in arguments of another function. Then use the syntax as the one in the example to run the functions.

```
Utils['sortBy']('price')
```

```js
const Utils = {
  sortBy: (a) => `sortBy ${a}`,
  startAt: (b) => `startAt ${b}`
}

const filters = [{
    "operator": "sortBy",
    "value": "price"
  },
  {
    "operator": "startAt",
    "value": "7"
  }
]

const anotherFunction = (arg1, arg2) => {
  console.log(arg1);
  console.log(arg2);
  
  return ':)';
}


const result = anotherFunction(...filters.map((f) => Utils[f.operator](f.value)))
```

Comment: You need to spread the resulting array.